# Excel Index and Match function with multiple criteria not searching the next record

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet wherein I need to find data based on multiple search criteria. I have used the Index with Match function to find the first record in the spreadsheet however I am unable to get to the next record in the data set.

The file name is "Safety Stats" and the data is in the [Occupational Injuries] tab. I need to find all records where the month is pervious month, the "Employee/Contractor" column is "Employee" and the "Injury Type" column is not "First Aid" or "Reported Only". You can see here: [image]

My function is locating the first occurrence however I am unable to find the next record in the data set. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Here is the function I have written.

```
{=IF(
    ISNA(
        INDEX(
            '[Safety Stats.xlsx]Occupational Injuries'!$C$5:$C$128,
            MATCH(1,
                ('[Safety Stats.xlsx]Occupational Injuries'!$A$5:$A$128=TEXT(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1),"MMMM")) * 
                ('[Safety Stats.xlsx]Occupational Injuries'!$F$5:$F$128="Employee") * 
                ('[Safety Stats.xlsx]Occupational Injuries'!$I$5:$I$128<>"First Aid") * 
                ('[Safety Stats.xlsx]Occupational Injuries'!$I$5:$I$128<>"Reported Only"),0))),"",
                INDEX('[Safety Stats.xlsx]Occupational Injuries'!$C$5:$C$128,
                    MATCH(1,
                    ('[Safety Stats.xlsx]Occupational Injuries'!$A$5:$A$128=$Y$9) * 
                    ('[Safety Stats.xlsx]Occupational Injuries'!$F$5:$F$128="Employee") * 
                    ('[Safety Stats.xlsx]Occupational Injuries'!$I$5:$I$128<>"First Aid") * 
                    ('[Safety Stats.xlsx]Occupational Injuries'!$I$5:$I$128<>"Reported Only"),0
                )
            )
    )
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Filter the list by these criteria? Then maybe use filters instead of lookup formulas.

Comment: I want excel to pull data based on my criteria from this spreadsheet into a different excel report every month. I am using this formula in the other report

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of all records that meet the criteria, then you won't get far with a lookup formula. You may want to consider a different approach where you filter the data source.

You could turn on AutoFilter in the Data ribbon and then select the values in the column headers.

If you want to copy the filtered results, you may want to take a look at Advanced Filter. You can define filter criteria in spreadsheet cells, then run the Advanced Filter and have the results copied to a different worksheet.

Edit: the formula approach is not suitable. You need a different approach. Consider a pivot table with filters and/or slicers that  looks at the original data. When new data is added, refresh the pivot table.

Or, use Power Query, a free add-in from Microsoft for Excel 2010. You can define the query once with all the filters, then refresh it when the data source has been changed.

Comment: I want excel to pull data based on my criteria from this spreadsheet into a different excel report every month. I am using this formula in the other report.

Comment: I added a few suggestions to my answer.